# trigger pendsv from svc || trigger systick manually cortex m4

Tags: c++, c, arm, cortex-m

i am currently working on an arm cortex m4. I implemented a simple context switch by triggering PendSV (which does the switch) from the SysTick interrupt. I tried to implement a `void delay(int ms)` function via SVC. It should work like this:

1. Trigger SVC
2. The Delay function writes delay into task_info
3. The scheduler decrements delay in task_info next time it's the tasks turn and skips the task.
4. When delay is equal to 0 the task gets scheduled normally again

The problem is, that i would like to trigger the context switch after the delay function has written the respective value to the task_info. Else the delay would only have effect after the next context switch. I tried to trigger PendSV from the SVC interrupt. Sadly this seems not to work.

With my former implementation of the delay function i got into memory usage faults when more than one task called the function at the same time.

Due to the current idea being more precise in timing i would like it to work. Help is greatly appreciated.

PS: Just for clarity, the delay value in `int ms` is multiplied with a factor derived from the clock speed and the SysTick frequency.

Comment: There's no reason why triggering PendSV from an SVC handler shouldn't work, I've done it many times.  I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.  Could you try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm sorry. After a short break and reading the question out to myself, i found the problem. PendSV was triggered, but due to me not calling the scheduler the task was not skipped.